# SQL CLR integration with .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, clrstoredprocedure

I am developing one website by using .net 2008. My Project is Website type and I  am using SQL CLR integration, I am new in CLR integration, my code is like that

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void abc()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlPipe sp;
        sp = SqlContext.Pipe;
        sp.Send("string");
    }
}
```

Now I want to know how this 'abc' stored procedure call in SQL. Should I use new project and then SQL server project? But I want to integrate in website.
Please provide me step by step solution.

Comment: Refer this link: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/

Comment: ya i saw this link.. but this is not in website type. this is a new project based on sql server project. i hv to integrate in .net website

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to add your CLR procedure to the database, or how to call it from your ASP.NET code? Both those operations are well documented and there are many questions about them on this site, so it would help if you can be more precise about your goal.